# Height and width attribute of embedded SVG is not being reflected in the browser

Tags: svg

When I try to embed an svg within another svg, the height and width of the embedded svg is not respected by the browser and it just defaults  to the size of the painted element inside of the svg. This is a problem as I wish to show the effect of a change to the view box attribute on the embedded svg and will hence need some space around the actual element painted into the svg. Is there a way to force the browser to respect the embedded svg's height and width attributes

[Example code](https://codepen.io/jonathan-werrey-easterbrook/pen/WNQeBMz)

```html
<div id='main'>
 <svg id="svg-container" width="1200" height="600"  >

<defs>
  <marker id="1" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="markerWidth" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10">
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2" fill="rgb(255,0,0)"></circle>
  </marker>
</defs>

<line x1="0" y1="200" x2="100%" y2="200" stroke='white' stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray='5,5'/>
<line x1="0" y1="400" x2="100%" y2="400" stroke='white' stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray='5,5'/>
<line x1="200" y1="0" x2="200" y2="100%" stroke='white' stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray='5,5'/>
<line x1="400" y1="0" x2="400" y2="100%" stroke='white' stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray='5,5'/>
<line x1="600" y1="0" x2="600" y2="100%" stroke='white' stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray='5,5'/>
<line x1="800" y1="0" x2="800" y2="100%" stroke='white' stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray='5,5'/>
<line x1="1000" y1="0" x2="1000" y2="100%" stroke='white' stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray='5,5'/>

<svg x='0' y="0" id="svg-1" width="200" height="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="red" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="5" ></circle>
 </svg>

 <svg x='200' y="0" id="svg-2" width="200" height="200">
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="#27f902" stroke-width="2" ></circle>
</svg>

<svg x='400' y="0" id="svg-2" width="200" height="200">
 <rect x="50" y="50" rx="50" ry="20" width="100" height="100" fill="rgb(201, 52, 235)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" ></circle>
 </svg>
   
 </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The containers are bigger than their contents so what do you expect to happen? Note also that id values must be unique, duplication makes the document invalid.